# Running Puppeteer tests in order with Jest

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, puppeteer

I'm using Jest Puppeteer and I have a situation where I'd like to run my login test (which sets cookie/localStorage for the authentication) first and run the others after, however, I know that Jest doesn't work this way - as it searches the local filesystem and runs tests based on the patterns in the filename, and the order in which they run is different.

I'm not entirely sure I'm going about this the correct way as I'm relying on a test to set the the authentication session for the other tests.

Is it possible to do the above, or do I need to rethink my approach?

Comment: I'd rethink the approach ... is there any way to set the auth data outside of a test? Typically I'd put something like this in a `beforeAll` hook.

Comment: It is possible but I wanted to actually test the login flow. 

The steps for the login:

 on the homepage I check if the user  is logged in, if not then redirect to a seperate website for  authentication, the fields are completed and when the form is submitted the user is redirect back to the dashboard.

Comment: In that case I'd have both ... a test for the login flow and a `beforeAll` hook that sets up auth for other test cases.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a timely answer. I had similar  problem. I am able to run tests in order by nesting describe blocks as shown below. my tests are in separate files that I require here.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const login = require('./login');
const upload = require('./upload');
let browser;

beforeAll(async () => {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        devtools: true,
        slowMo: 50
    });

})
describe('test suite', () => {
    describe('login', () => {

        test('url is correct', async () => {

            const url = await login();
            expect(url).toBe('https://uat2.onplanapp.com/#/');


        }, 25000);

    });
    describe('upload', () => {


        test('file upload ok', async () => {
            url = await upload();
            console.log('page.url');

            expect(url).toBe('https://uat2.onplanapp.com/#/moduleLibrary');
            //expect(url).toBe('https://uat2.onplanapp.com/#/uploadFile');

        }, 10000);

    });
    afterAll(async done => {
        console.log('GOT TO AFTER ALL');
        browser.close()
        done();
    });

});
```